# Pre-image resistant but not 2nd pre-image resistant?

Tags: hash, preimage-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

Are there any cryptographic hash functions for which there is a known pre-image attack, or a known second pre-image attack, but not both?

The attack doesn't have to be practical - just anything that beats the security claim of the hash function.

Intuitively, 2nd pre-image attacks would be easier to find than pre-image attacks, but I'm not aware of any examples or that either property implies the other.

I believe there are no known pre-image attacks on the common crop of hash functions in use today, so I'm interested in historic, obsolete and proposed-but-not-adopted hash functions, but [*not* toy hash functions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1018/4700) constructed specifically to demonstrate the possibility of such attacks.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I confused second-preimage with collision attacks - my bad.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A cryptographic hash function $f : \{0,1\}^{*} \to \{0,1\}^n$ has three properties: (1) preimage resistance, (2) second-preimage resistance, and (3) collision resistance. Even further, these properties form a hierarchy where each property implies the one before it, i.e., a collision-resistant function is also second-preimage resistant, and a second-preimage resistant function is also preimage-resistant (with a condition on $f$).

In the case of (3) ⇒ (2), it's not too hard to see why: if an adversary cannot find *any* colliding message pairs, then they certainly cannot find a colliding message when one of the messages is fixed.

However, (2) ⇒ (1) is substantially trickier. For some intuition, consider a second-preimage resistant hash function $f$ that was *not* preimage resistant (modeled by being given access to a preimage-finding oracle). Suppose you were given a $m_1$; then you could compute $H(m_1)$ and consult the oracle for the preimage of $H(m_1)$. The oracle would then return a $m_2$ such that $H(m_1) = H(m_2)$.

This is very nearly a second preimage. The only question is if $m_1 \ne m_2$. Intuitively, given that $f$ maps infinitely-many inputs to a finite number of outputs, there "should be" a high probability that $m_1 \ne m_2$. For all real-life hash functions, this is pretty much the case, so a second-preimage resistant hash function should not lack preimage resistance.

However, it is possible to define "pathological" hash functions that have perfect, provable second-preimage resistance but not preimage resistance. The example given in [chapter 9 of the *Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap9.pdf) is this:

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 0 || x & \text{if } x \text{ is } n \text{ bits long}\\
 1 || g(x) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

where $g(x)$ is a collision-resistant hash function. In this case, for digests beginning with $0$, it's trivial to find a preimage (indeed, it's just the identity function), but such cases are provably second-preimage resistant, as there are no possible second preimages. In other words, this $f$ is bijective across the space of $n$-bit inputs.

To be more precise about when (2) ⇒ (1), Rogaway and Shrimpton have presented a theoretical analysis of the various relations between the three properties listed above in their [*Cryptographic Hash-Function Basics*](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/relates.pdf). Essentially, their analysis treats a hash function as having a finite, fixed-length domain, i.e. $f : \{0,1\}^m \to \{0,1\}^n$, wherein they show

1. "conventional implications", like the implication (3) ⇒ (2); these are essentially "true" implications in the sense that they are unconditional, and
2. "provisional implications", like the implication that (2) ⇒ (1); these are conditional in nature, relying on how much $f$ compresses the message space (as the message space gets larger relative to the digest space, the "stronger" the implication in a probabilistic sense).

So, provisional implications are *essentially* true if a hash function compresses the message space to a sufficient degree. (The "sufficient" example they provide is a hash compressing 256-bit messages to 128 bits.) Hence, second-preimage resistance implies preimage resistance only if the function in question compresses its input sufficiently. For length-preserving, length-extending, or low-compression functions, second-preimage resistance does not necessarily imply preimage resistance (as stated by the authors on page 8 about halfway down the page).

This should be intuitive given the above algorithm for finding second preimages given a preimage oracle. If you are expanding 6-bit inputs to 256 bits, it's actually quite unlikely that a preimage oracle would be able to find a second preimage. This isn't a formal argument, by any means, but it's a nice heuristic one.

---

Now, back to real life. Given the above algorithm for using a preimage oracle to find second preimages, I would not expect any real-life hash functions to have preimage attacks and not second-preimage attacks, especially since real hash functions typically compress data well.

On the other hand, I'm not personally aware of any historically-used, non-toy cryptographic hash function which has a second-preimage attack but not a preimage attack. Typically, collision resistance is the first thing attacked by cryptanalysts since it is (in a sense) the "hardest" property to satisfy. But if a hash function is found to be broken with regard to collisions, cryptanalysts typically go straight for the heart: preimage attacks. So, I don't know how much luck you'll have trying to find such a hash function.

You can look at the [hash function lounge](http://www.larc.usp.br/~pbarreto/hflounge.html) for some historic hash functions; it hasn't been updated since 2008, apparently, but still contains some useful info. I glanced through a few attacks and found mostly collision and preimage attacks, but you may have more luck.

Comment: The easiest way to construct a provably secondary preimage resistant (hash) function, is to choose a bijective function. You might want to expand on that.

Comment: @HenrickHellström: Usually, hash functions are assumed to be maps from $\{0,1\}^*$ to $\{0,1\}^n$ for some fixed $n$. No such map is a bijection. But yes, if we're allowed to narrow down the domain or expand the range of our hash function enough to make it bijective (or at least injective), it's easy to make even trivially weak hash functions 2nd preimage resistant. In particular, the identity function is clearly 2nd preimage and collision resistant, but finding first preimages is trivial.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: The example in HAC is a function $h(x) = 1|x$ if $x$ is $n$ bits long, $h(x) = 0|g(x)$ otherwise. If $g(x)$ is a cryptographic hash function, then $h(x)$ will be collision resistant and secondary preimage resistant, but not primary preimage resistant.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: The question I implied with my first question was if Reid might tighten up the argument that a not "pathological" hash function that is not primary preimage resistant, *must* lack secondary preimage resistance. I don't know, but it doesn't seem impossible, given a more technical definition of "pathological".

Comment: @HenrickHellström: Per your recommendation, I've fleshed out the answer quite a bit. It's quite lengthy now, but contains much more good content imo.

Comment: Thanks for the info and good explanations and also the pointer to the hash function lounge - see my answer for what came of it.

Comment: There are some hashes with use more rounds for finalization than between consuming inputs. For those it's pretty likely that first pre-images are much harder to find than second pre-images.

Comment: It is worth noting that the Rogaway/Shrimpton paper defines all notions of hash function security that they cover in terms of the adversaries' advantage becoming negligible. i.e. the theoretical crypto approach. When people in general talk about collision or preimage resistance, on the other hand, they often think of concrete bounds like $2^{n/2}$ expected work factor for finding an essentially new collision pair. Under these notions, many of the usual implications _don't_ hold. For instance, collision resistance in this sense implies _nothing_ about attacks with $> 2^{n/2}$ work factor...

Answer (score 8):

In their paper [Second Preimages on $n$-Bit Hash Functions for Much Less than $2^n$ Work](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/304.pdf), Kelsey and Schneier provide:

> a second preimage attack on all $n$-bit iterated hash functions with Damgard-Merkle strengthening and $n$-bit intermediate states, allowing a second preimage to be found for a $2^k$-message-block message with about $k\times2^{n/2+1}+ 2^{n-k+1}$ work

as opposed to the expected $2^n$ work. This is firmly in the realms of theoretical attacks, but meets the criteria of being a second-preimage attack, not a preimage attack, and it applies to all the commonly used hash functions prior to SHA3.

The example they provide: a second pre-image can be found for a $2^{60}$ byte message processed with SHA1 in $2^{106}$ work rather than $2^{160}$. This is the largest message SHA1 can process; if we pick a more plausible but still large message size, say a SHA1 hash over a 4TB disk, or approximately $2^{38}$ message blocks, the work to find a second pre-image is approximately $38 \times 2^{{160/2} + 1} + 2^{160-38+1} \approx 2^{123}$.

Thanks to Reid for the pointer to the [Hash Function Lounge](http://www.larc.usp.br/~pbarreto/hflounge.html) where I found this paper.

Comment: Good to see you found some useful information! Apparently, what I should have used was the search function instead of trying to spot attacks on some historic hash functions...

Answer (score 1):

Great answers here already! That said, the specific example given in Reid's answer kind of confuses my brain. So, here's a really simple example, to help out anyone else in the same boat.

Take any cryptographic hash function $H_0$, and define $H_1(x) = H_0(r(x))$, where $r$ is defined to be the function that strips at most one trailing zero from the message it's given. Clearly $H_1$ is not second-preimage resistant, since if we fix a message $x$, we can easily find another message (namely $x \| 0$) that collides with it. Nevertheless, solving $y = H_1(x)$ is not really any easier than solving $y = H_0(x)$. To see this, assume toward a contradiction that we manage to find a message $x$ such that $y = H_1(x).$ Clearly, this message must also satisfy $y = H_0(r(x))$. Since we've found $x$, we can also find $r(x)$. But this contradicts the assumption that finding a value $x'$ with $y = H_0(x')$ should be infeasible - QED.

More generally, if we truncate the original message, or otherwise ignore easily-describable bits of information contained in that message, this will always break second preimage-resistance, but it will often leave first preimage resistance intact.