# Testing hash functions for collision resistance

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

I was hoping to implement a software that allows testing a user-defined hash function for cryptographic properties *(Meant to pique interest in cryptographic hash function for a school showcase)*, as well as compare them with well-known hash function to identify their hash functions strong points & weak points. However the property collision-resistance got me into a bit of a pickle.

The first obvious thought that occurred to me was the **Birthday Paradox Attack**, where given that we only with to find an instance of a hash collision 
*(henceprob of hash collision should assumed to be **0.5** or above)*
thus if the hash function finds a collision on ***2^(n/2)*** operations consistently.

The second option that I considered was to count the length of the hash value & determine the size of the pool for all possible hash values. From there on we prepare a plaintext list of that size to check if the hash values are distributed evenly across the hash value space.

The problem with the two proposed solution I given was that given that the hash value length is significantly large *(256 bits or more)* this might prove to be an hassle given the large amount of brute force needed to thoroughly check for collisions. Also I was hoping for a more refined way to identify their hash functions flaws.

I am currently looking at length extension attack, the way it functions sounds like a type of [differential cryptanalysis attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11327/are-there-attacks-that-break-collision-resistance-but-not-preimage-resistance), I was hoping that I can use this to derive a collision using the padding exploit. *(By understanding how they pad. maybe I can use the same type of trick to result in a collision, am still unsure of how exactly it works so I might be completely wrong here)*

Other than the methods mentioned above, is there any other ways that I can accomplish this?

Comment: Testing (implementations of) cryptographic algorithms as a black box is doomed to be useless as a convincing argument (much less as proof) that they work as expected. At best, such test can disprove that they work as expected, for a small class of possible failure modes.

Comment: Hence it is essentially impossible to prove a cryptographic hash function works without prior knowledge of the algorithm structure and inner working?

Comment: Yes. And even with prior knowledge of the algorithm structure and inner working, the best we can do is give a convincing argument of security, not a proof in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think calculation of probability is not a good idea. Because your pool is gonna greater when you want to work with complex hash algorithms (for ex: sha256/512...)It may work just for md5 or sha1.
I suggest you to check out also Linear Cryptanalysis Attack to understand Differential Cryptanalysis deeply.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, any recommended links to get started? The problem is I would be accepting user-defined hash functions as a class file, so i'm guessing for cryptanalysis I would need the .java file & also certain pattern matching algorithm to identify key aspects of the hash functions.

Comment: Java may not be proper for this kind of algorithms. If i were you i would use python or c. I suggest you to check this article:  http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/documents/WATANABE_cr_criteria.pdf